# How to do "position: sticky" on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can't find how to do something like this https://codepen.io/dexnick4501/pen/dyKzGKq on react native.

I tried the method ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices.
He can't take a sub element

```
<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
<View> <-- Here element select
  <Header /> <-- Here element not select
</View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) with [stickySectionHeadersEnabled](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#stickysectionheadersenabled). Something like this

```
<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
  )}
  stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
    <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
  )}
/>
```